# Plants are wilting and looking sick

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

This plant (unknown species) has very large leaves and came in a small pot. After about a month of weekly watering (we were told 30-40oz once a week--and usually split half morning, half afternoon) both plants are wilting. My initial impression was that this size pot is way too small.

Obviously the plants are not doing great and I am wondering:

1. Do they need more water, and how much?
2. Do they need a bigger pot?
3. What species is this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a prize-winning plant. Your results are outstanding. Not doing well? It does not need a bigger pot, but aesthetically, yes, for more balance. Some kind of Arum, similar to Elephant Ear - Colocasia esculenta.

Comment: To be clear, the leaves are not supposed to be so low, the stems supporting those leaves are bending and the leaves wilting to the floor. :-(

Comment: Tropical plants want more light, but the languid look might be its nature. Tie it upright. Watering twice a day is not common, and a liter a day is a lot unless it should sit in water all day long.

Comment: Good idea to tie it! We are doing just once a week not once per day...but maybe we should try *twice* a week for a while??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second photo is one of the larger Alocasias, probably Alocasia Borneo Black. It needs a much, much bigger pot with drainage holes - the only reason it's drying out so frequently is because it's in such a tiny pot - these plants can get up to 12 feet tall in the right conditions. This is also the reason some of the lower leaves are not upright. They like bright daylight, but not direct sun unless it's early morning or late evening sun and prefer a free draining, light but fertile soil. They prefer moist but not soaking wet soil, so if you repot, water heavily,allowing the excess to drain away freely from the bottom of the pot, then water ongoing as the top of the soil feels just a tiny bit dry on the surface. The other plant is most likely another variety of Alocasia, hard to say because the photo doesn't clearly show the leaf colour and venation - it may be a smaller variety, but likely also needs a larger pot with drainage holes.